# When deleting a lot of files everything is very slow

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

I don't know this is a bug or just a limitation of hard disk -- when trying to delete a lot of files (e.g. empty trash directory when it contains lot of files), everything becomes very slow!

From what I saw, *everything* can be defined as operations to hard disk:

- Saving a VIM buffer to disk
- opening a web page in browser
- navigating in directories

Is there any solution for this? How can I prevent this problem?

My machine has 16 GB or RAM, and Intel Core i7 processor.

---

Relevant output:

```
$ cat /sys/block/[hs]d?/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq 
noop [deadline] cfq 
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       418G  147G  251G  37% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7,8G  4,0K  7,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  1,1M  1,6G   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            7,8G   42M  7,8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       487M  3,4M  483M   1% /boot/efi
```

My hard disk has the following specs:

- Type HDD
- 750GB
- HDD Rotation speed 7200RPM
- HDD Interface SATA II

Comment: Which file system(s) and which mount flags do you use?

Comment: @DavidFoerster What do you mean? :-) I just pressed *Empty* button in Trash directory, using Nautiulus. But this happens when I do `rm -rf lot-of-files`.

Comment: I forgot one: which CPU and I/O scheduler(s) do you use? All of those factors have a large impact on how fast file deletion will be on your system. In addition the schedulers influences how much other applications will be affected by I/O intense operations. Do you know how to answer these questions or do you need help with that?

Comment: How can I find what *I/O scheduler(s)* I use?

Comment: Like this: `cat /sys/block/[hs]d?/queue/scheduler`. The mount flags can be observed in the output of `mount`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Updated the question with this output.

Comment: Wouldn't you have by chance a slow device connected (USB pen drive, whatever)? Even if not the main drive? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107722/52205 --- Hope it helps. Otherwise --- which disk are you using? (results of `df -h`).

Comment: It looks like you either have SSDs instead of hard disks or you chose a different default scheduler. Generally CFQ is recommended for rotational media (as the other may result in poor performance for random access) and No-op or Deadline for non-rotational because the fast random access doesn't justify the computational overhead of CFQ.

Comment: @Rmano I added that output.

Comment: @DavidFoerster See the HDD specs (edited question). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to switch to the [CFQ scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ), because it is more optimised towards rotational media:

```sh
echo -n cfq | sudo tee /sys/block/[hs]d?/queue/scheduler > /dev/null
```

You can benchmark file system performance with IOzone (package name `iozone3`).

### More on the [CFQ scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ)

- http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch13lev1sec5
- [Graphical representation](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Linux_I/O_Scheduler#Grafische_Darstellung) (German article but English diagram annotations)

Comment: Can you explain a little what is a *CFQ scheduler*? How can I test if everything worked fine?

Comment: I leave the explaining to other people and added some links to articles about CFQ.

Comment: Can you take a look at [this question too](http://askubuntu.com/q/541773/148451)? It seems to be related to HDD operations.